# How to make several columns mandatory basing on 1 other column

Tags: vba

I'm having an issue making 5 columns to be filled mandatory (E I J L M) if the cells in a column (C) is filled.

i have written this code but i really having trouble linking the column C to that :(

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, _
Cancel As Boolean)


Dim rngCell As Range
Dim lngLstRow As Long, lngTCols As Long
Dim lngRowCheck(1 To 5) As String


lngRowCheck(1) = "E"
lngRowCheck(2) = "I"
lngRowCheck(3) = "J"
lngRowCheck(4) = "L"
lngRowCheck(5) = "M"

lngLstRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

For i = 1 To UBound(lngRowCheck)
    For Each rngCell In Range(lngRowCheck(i) & "2:" & lngRowCheck(i) & lngLstRow)
        If rngCell.Value = "" Then
            MsgBox ("Please enter an input in cell " & rngCell.Address)
            rngCell.Select
        End If
    Next
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Could you be more specific? If you could put an expected output.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if the Column C is empty before going to loop into the columns.

Code below is doing what you after, but why check only when workbook is before save? If those columns are madatory for that particular worksheet, you should use the worksheet events (**Worksheet_Activate**, **Worksheet_SelectionChange**), tracking the current selected row and when selection changed row, check for column C, etc.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

    Dim rngCell As Range
    Dim lngLstRow As Long, lngRow As Long
    Dim arrColsToCheck As Variant, oItem As Variant

    arrColsToCheck = Array("E", "I", "J", "L", "M")

    With ActiveSheet ' Only 1 sheet in workbook?
        lngLstRow = .UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row
        For lngRow = 1 To lngLstRow
            ' Check if column C is filled (not empty)
            If Not IsEmpty(.Cells(lngRow, "C")) Then
                ' Check the mandatory columns
                For Each oItem In arrColsToCheck
                    Set rngCell = .Cells(lngRow, oItem)
                    If IsEmpty(rngCell) Then
                        rngCell.Select
                        MsgBox ("Please enter an input in cell " & rngCell.Address(0, 0))
                    End If
                    Set rngCell = Nothing
                Next
            End If
        Next lngRow
    End With

End Sub
```

For code on the Worksheet that requires this check:

```
Option Explicit

Private ActiveRow As Long

Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    ActiveRow = ActiveCell.row
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.row <> ActiveRow Then
        ' Call the Column C check for Madatory fields, passing the ActiveRow to it
        ' You implement this Sub with a "Long" as argument
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks ! 
I works on the sleceted sheet.
I have actually 6 sheets in the workbook.

Comment: @SPSydPierr If all these 6 worksheets require the same check, you need to create a generic sub in a normal module, and paste 2nd part into each worksheet module and calling the Sub (pass the Target Range instead of the row). The generic sub can get the worksheet from the range.